# Trace the id's that constructed a zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

Once a zip element has been constructed, say for example from two lists,

```
z = zip(l1, l2)
```

Is there a method to get from `z` the id's of the constructing `l1` and `l2` lists, or is `z` completely ignorant of its origin?

I did not find any method that seem relevant, but perhaps...

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this information?

Comment: There's no way to get those ids from `z` (in fact, there is no guarantee that `l1` and `l2` still exist at some later point in your program even if `z` still does -- in that case, the `id` could even be the IDs of completely different objects ...).  Why do you want this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'id'? And no, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) seems to indicate otherwise. Note the equivalent code they provide.

Comment: The closest you can do is: `x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))`, but that copies `x` and `y`y by value and doesn't return the information you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - At the moment I'm trying to deal with a tough one - Plain curiosity. Hopefully that's not considered bad conduct :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's theoretically possible in limited cases. You might want to do something like this in interactive mode or a `pdb` debugging session if it's the only way to get at an object you forgot to keep a reference to, but it's not something you should ever use in a program.

Let's take a look at what references a `zip` iterator reports to the garbage collector:

```
>>> import gc
>>> gc.get_referents(zip([1], [2]))
[(<list_iterator object at 0x7fcb4764dcf8>, <list_iterator object at 0x7fcb4764dbe0>), (None, None)]
```

We see references to a tuple of two underlying iterators, and a tuple of `None`s. The tuple of `None`s is part of an optimization `zip` uses to save time on allocating output tuples. It isn't interesting to us. The `list_iterator` objects are more interesting, but you asked for the lists, not list iterators.

An iterator over a list needs to keep a reference to the list, and since this reference could be involved in a reference cycle, the list iterator needs to report this reference to the garbage collector when requested. Thus, if we use `gc.get_referents` again:

```
>>> z = zip([1], [2])
>>> gc.get_referents(z)
[(<list_iterator object at 0x7fcb4764db70>, <list_iterator object at 0x7fcb4764dd30>), (None, None)]
>>> l_iters = _[0]
>>> gc.get_referents(l_iters[0])[0]
[1]
>>> gc.get_referents(l_iters[1])[0]
[2]
```

We can retrieve the lists.

Comment: Oh sprite! I wouldn't need that *wrapper class*  after all

Comment: This is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` does not provide the functionality that you seek.

You could instead create a *wrapper class* that provides this functionality:

```
class Zip:

    def __init__(self, func=zip):
        self.ids = None
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.ids = [id(a) for a in args]
        return self.func(*args)
```

And can be used as such:

```
>>> z = Zip()
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> list(z(l1, l2))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
>>> z.ids
[52203152, 52334640]
```

However, there is not a guarantee that at some later point in your code, the original list objects are still in possession of these ids.